# How to make it possible to add any number of slick sliders with the same class to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

The user through the admin panel can add any number of sliders to the page. How to make all sliders with the same class initialized?

How do I make sure that the control buttons for each slider are applied separately, and not just for the last slider?

Now the buttons only work for the last slider.

```js
$('.sliderBox').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  prevArrow: $('.sliderLeftBtn'),
  nextArrow: $('.sliderRightBtn'),
  dots: true,
  appendDots: $('.sliderControl'),
});
```

```css
.smallSlider-Item img{
  width: 200px;
  background: #red;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="sliderBox">
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="sliderControl">
  <div class="arrowLeft sliderLeftBtn"></div>
  <div class="arrowRight sliderRightBtn"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="sliderBox">
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
  <a class="smallSlider-Item" href="">
<img src="img/smallSlider/k.png" alt="" class="smallSlider-ItemImg">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="sliderControl">
  <div class="arrowLeft sliderLeftBtn"></div>
  <div class="arrowRight sliderRightBtn"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant markup for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry, I will add in a couple of minutes

Comment: Here is a link to the codepen, now I will add it to the stack.  https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/OJMBWxz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by running through each slider element. Since there were some errors in your markup, I have edited everything a little bit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-container').each(function(index, element) {
    var $sliderBox = $(element).find('.slider-box'),
      $sliderControls = $sliderBox.next('.slider-controls');
    
    $sliderBox.slick({
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
      prevArrow: $sliderControls.find('.slider-button.button-prev'),
      nextArrow: $sliderControls.find('.slider-button.button-next'),
      appendDots: $sliderControls,
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.slider-controls .slick-dots {
  position: static;
  bottom: initial;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-box">
    <a href="#01"><h3>01</h3></a>
    <a href="#02"><h3>02</h3></a>
    <a href="#03"><h3>03</h3></a>
    <a href="#04"><h3>04</h3></a>
    <a href="#05"><h3>05</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-controls">
    <button class="slider-button button-prev">&lt; Prev</button>
    <button class="slider-button button-next">Next &gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-box">
    <a href="#06"><h3>06</h3></a>
    <a href="#07"><h3>07</h3></a>
    <a href="#08"><h3>08</h3></a>
    <a href="#09"><h3>09</h3></a>
    <a href="#10"><h3>10</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-controls">
    <button class="slider-button button-prev">&lt; Prev</button>
    <button class="slider-button button-next">Next &gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank. I tried to do this, but the only thing is that the arrows do not work for me.  $('.sliderBox').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;
    $(this).slick({
    variableWidth: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    dots: true,
        appendArrows: "#" + carouselId + " .sliderControl",
        prevArrow: '<a>Previous</a>',
        nextArrow: '<a>Next</a>'
    });
});

Comment: I would recommend you to make a `div` around the slider box and the slider controls. But where exactly is now the problem - do you can't change your markup?